# Unable to export in parallel from Exasol using pyexasol

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing, exasol

I'm attempting to fetch data from Exasol using PyExasol, in parallel. I'm following the example here - https://github.com/badoo/pyexasol/blob/master/examples/14_parallel_export.py

My code looks like this :

```
import multiprocessing
import pyexasol
import pyexasol.callback as cb

class ExportProc(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, node):
        self.node = node
        self.read_pipe, self.write_pipe = multiprocessing.Pipe(False)

        super().__init__()

    def start(self):
        super().start()
        self.write_pipe.close()

    def get_proxy(self):
        return self.read_pipe.recv()

    def run(self):
        self.read_pipe.close()

        http = pyexasol.http_transport(self.node['host'], self.node['port'], pyexasol.HTTP_EXPORT)
        self.write_pipe.send(http.get_proxy())
        self.write_pipe.close()

        pd1 = http.export_to_callback(cb.export_to_pandas, None)
        print(f"{self.node['idx']}:{len(pd)}")

EXASOL_HOST = "<IP-ADDRESS>:8563"
EXASOL_USERID = "username"
EXASOL_PASSWORD = "password"

c = pyexasol.connect(dsn=EXASOL_HOST, user=EXASOL_USERID, password=EXASOL_PASSWORD, compression=True)

nodes = c.get_nodes(10)

pool = list()
proxy_list = list()

for n in nodes:
  proc = ExportProc(n)
  proc.start()
  proxy_list.append(proc.get_proxy())
  pool.append(proc)

c.export_parallel(proxy_list, "SELECT * FROM SOME_SCHEMA.SOME_TABLE", export_params={'with_column_names': True})

stmt = c.last_statement()

r = stmt.fetchall()
```

At the last statement, I'm getting the following error and unable to fetch any results.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ExaRuntimeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-911615> in <module>
----> 1 r = stmt.fetchall()

/local_disk0/pythonVirtualEnvDirs/virtualEnv-01515a25-967f-4b98-aa10-6ac03c978ce2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyexasol/statement.py in fetchall(self)
     85 
     86     def fetchall(self):
---> 87         return [row for row in self]
     88 
     89     def fetchcol(self):

/local_disk0/pythonVirtualEnvDirs/virtualEnv-01515a25-967f-4b98-aa10-6ac03c978ce2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyexasol/statement.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     85 
     86     def fetchall(self):
---> 87         return [row for row in self]
     88 
     89     def fetchcol(self):

/local_disk0/pythonVirtualEnvDirs/virtualEnv-01515a25-967f-4b98-aa10-6ac03c978ce2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyexasol/statement.py in __next__(self)
     53         if self.pos_total >= self.num_rows_total:
     54             if self.result_type != 'resultSet':
---> 55                 raise ExaRuntimeError(self.connection, 'Attempt to fetch from statement without result set')
     56 
     57             raise StopIteration

ExaRuntimeError: 
(
    message  =>  Attempt to fetch from statement without result set
    dsn      =>  <IP-ADDRESS>:8563
    user     =>  username
    schema   =>  
)
```

It seems that the type of the returned statement is not 'resultSet' but 'rowCount'. Any help on what I'm doing wrong or why the type of statement is ''rowCount' ?

Answer (score 0):

PyEXASOL creator is here. Please not in case of parallel HTTP transport you have to process data chunks inside child processes. Your data set is available in `pd1` DataFrame.

You should not be calling `.fetchall()` in the main process in case of parallel processing.

I suggest to check the complete examples, especially example 14 (parallel export).

Hope it helps!